# Return confirm window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with an `if else` statement which will only display depending on the statement. My confirm window is not working. It will just go to the log-out page without the confirmation.

My code:

```
else
{
    echo "
              <td class='td1' align='center'>
                  <a href='logout.php' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure you want to Log Out?')'><img src='./buttons/logout1.png' width='50' height='35' alt='Log Out'></a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

    ";}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the return before confirm? I don't think that's needed

Comment: @Bálint, yes i already did. Still not showing the confirm window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table><tr>
<td class='td1' align='center'>
<a href='logout.php' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Log Out?')">Log Out</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Change your code to this

```
else
{
echo "
<td class='td1' align='center'>
<a href='logout.php' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to Log Out?')\"><img src='./buttons/logout1.png' width='50' height='35' alt='Log Out'></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

";}
```

1. Use escape sequence inside onlclick.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply replace your code with this because you have placed a return before confirm, but by JavaScript there is the confirm keyword which will give you functionality what you are expecting instead of return confirm. Just confirm will work.

```js
else
{
    echo "
              <td class='td1' align='center'>
                  <a href='logout.php' onclick='confirm('Are you sure you want to Log Out?')'><img src='./buttons/logout1.png' width='50' height='35' alt='Log Out'></a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

    ";}
```

Comment: At least tell him whaf and why.

Comment: try this onClick = confirm('are you sure you want to log out') by removing  '   ' from start at confirm and ending

Comment: @MuhafilSaiyed , i already tried that one still not, supposed to be working by now i dont know why not.

Comment: @Jannice Camaso check my second answer

Comment: @MuhafilSaiyed . Thanks! :)

Comment: if Answer help you @JanniceCamaso marked as answers or atleast Upvote :-D :)

Answer (score 0):

You either use

```css
<a href="whatever" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')"><img ...></a>
```

Note the return (confirm): The value returned by scripts in intrinsic events decides whether the default browser action is run or not; in case you need to run a big piece of code you can of course call another function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_delete() {
      return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
</script>
...
<a href="whatever" onclick="return confirm_delete()"><img ...></a>
```

Or else you can simply try this:

```js
onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double `""` instead of `''`. Then it's OK. Change to `onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to Log Out?')"`

```
<a href="logout.php" onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to Log Out?')"><img src='./buttons/logout1.png' width='50' height='35' alt='Log Out'> </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Be careful with your single quotes. Replace `´` by `"` in confirm:

Here is an example: jsfiddle.net/37z6wpmz/